# Wordpress UserIDs and WooCommerce CustomerIDs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to figure out whether a Wordpress UserID is always equal to a WooCommerce CustomerID.

I need to find this value to identify a user, but need to ensure that the IDs are always equal across both the WordPress and WooCommerce APIs.

Comment: If you have "guest checkout" functionality disabled then YES it will be always same. As WooCommerce customers are stored in same table `wp_users`. So the user id will be same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, in both cases ID of users are same**.
Users who registered through WooCommerce registrations form are also stored into the same wp_users table.
**Only difference is their role.** Through WooCommerce form registered user role is Customer and WordPress form through registered user role is Subscriber.